# In 22.10 my background no longer spans multiple monitors. Is there a fix?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, desktop-background

Before I upgraded to 22.10 I had a nice background (a map) designed to span my 3 monitors. I've had to change it as this option no longer seems to be available and the background was massively distorted and mirrored on each screen. Is there any way to get it back and use my map background image spanning the three monitors.

Comment: Depending on what flavor of Ubuntu you are using, i.e. Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc. makes a difference on how the default application handles wallpapers.  Ubuntu doesn't natively handle multiple monitors with different / spanned wallpapers.  I would recommend you use an application like the hydrapaper flatpak.

Answer (score 1):

Set a backgroung you want and run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options spanned
```

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf editor and use it to change the keys in /org/gnome/desktop/background set picture-options to "spanned" and picture-uri to point to your background image.